# Ajax script, having trouble fetching PHP $_GET variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im having tough time fetching PHP $_GET variable with Ajax script, the goal is to update MySql table with same script. This is my PHP/HTML script for fetching and displaying data:

```
session_start();
require_once ('dbconnect.php');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT p_id, p_name, p_authors, p_corresponding, p_email, p_cauthor, p_abstract, p_keywords, p_jname, p_date FROM papers INNER JOIN users ON papers.user_id = users.user_id WHERE p_url = '$val' AND username='{$_SESSION['user']}'");
$last = mysql_num_rows($query);
$output1 = "";
$outarray1 = array();
  if ($last > 0) {
    while ($output1 = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $outarray1[] = $output1;
      if(is_array($outarray1)){
        foreach($outarray1 as $values){
        $id = $values['p_id'];
        $paper = $values['p_name'];
        $author = $values['p_authors'];
        $corresponding = $values['p_corresponding'];
        $mail = $values['p_email'];
        $coauthors = $values['p_cauthor'];
        $abstract = $values['p_abstract'];
        $keywords = $values['p_keywords'];
        $journal = $values['p_jname'];
        $date = $values['p_date'];
}
  }
    }   
      } 
echo <<<HERE
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="memberModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Edit Paper Details</h4>
</div>
</div>                           
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Paper</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>Corresponding author</th>
    <th>Mail</th>
    <th>Co-authors</th>
    <th>Abstract</th>
    <th>Keywords</th>
    <th>Journal</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
        </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>{$id}</td>
        <td>{$paper}</td>
        <td>{$author}</td>
        <td>{$corresponding}</td>
        <td>{$mail}</td>
        <td>{$coauthors}</td>
        <td>{$abstract}</td>
        <td>{$keywords}</td>
        <td>{$journal}</td>
        <td>{$date}</td>
    <td><a class="btn btn-small btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="<?php echo $id; ?>">Edit</a></td>                  
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is AJAX/JQuery script on same page for fetching ID variable from the table with $_GET method, but the problem is, when edit button is clicked, $_GET variable is not shown in URL, nor is picked up in editfile page, i can only see "Edit paper details" title, space below is empty, and it should show fields for editing record:

```
<script>
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
var modal = $(this);
var dataString = 'id=' + recipient;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "editdata.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    modal.find('.ct').html(data);
    },
    error: function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    }
    });  
    })
</script>
```

This is editfile script:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once ('dbconnect.php');
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="editdata.php" role="form">
            <div class="modal-body">             
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">ID
                    <input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>" readonly="true"/>
                </label>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Paper
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="paper" value="<?php echo $paper;?>" />
                </label>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Author
                    <input type="text" id="job" name="author" value="<?php echo $author;?>" />
                </label>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Corresponding author
                    <input type="text" id="service" name="corr" value="<?php echo $corresponding;?>" />
                </label>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email
                    <input type="text" id="education" name="mail" value="<?php echo $mail;?>" />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Co-authors
                    <input type="text" id="education" name="cauthors" value="<?php echo $coauthors;?>" />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Abstract
                    <input type="text" id="education" name="abstract" value="<?php echo $abstract;?>" />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Keywords
                    <input type="text" id="education" name="keywords" value="<?php echo $keywords;?>" />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Journal
                    <input type="text" id="education" name="journal" value="<?php echo $journal;?>" />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date
                    <input type="text" id="education" name="date" value="<?php echo $date;?>" />
                </label>
            </div>              
        </div>  
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Update" />&nbsp;
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</form>

<?php   
$id = $_GET['id']; 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $paper = $_POST['paper'];
    $author = $_POST['author'];
    $corresponding = $_POST['corr'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $coauthors = $_POST['cauthors'];
    $abstract = $_POST['abstract'];
    $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
    $journal = $_POST['journal'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
$qry = "UPDATE papers INNER JOIN users ON papers.user_id = users.user_id SET p_name = '$paper', p_authors = '$author', p_corresponding = '$corresponding', p_email = '$email', p_cauthor = '$coauthors', p_abstract = '$abstract', p_keywords = '$keywords', p_jname = '$journal', p_date = '$date' WHERE p_id = '$id' AND username = '{$_SESSION['user']}'";
    mysql_query($qry) or die("Error !".mysql_error());
    header("Location: home.php");
}

 ?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a warning: You're using PHP's `mysql_query()` and related functions. Please note that this API is deprecated (and will be removed entirely in the next PHP version). You should consider switching your code to use the PDO or mysqli libraries instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your "edit file script" is the `editdata.php` from your ajax.

1) I see where you're attempting to pass the ID over GET, but where are you getting all that post data from?

2) When using GET you don't relly need to specify that it's GET data, just append it to the URL...

```
url: "editdata.php?"+dataString,
```

Comment: Yeah, i have that one, forgot to c/p here

Comment: @Greedy - That's why it pays to post your actual code, or if you're going to change it, make sure it works as expected before posting it.

Comment: Sorry, ive modified it

Comment: @Greedy - It's still not your real code. `...etc...` is not compilable code.

Comment: @ Adelphia, ok now ive pasted it all

Comment: That values should be fetched from "value="<?php echo $id;?>" ?